# Find number of files with certain extension in directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script that will rename all the files in a directory with an extension of .jpg.  I figure that I would have to find the total number of files with the .jpg extension and iterate through all the files in the directory using a for loop.  My question is, how would I go about getting the total number of files with the .jpg extension within a directory?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about it this way: assume you have the number of files in the directory -- what will you do with that number?

Comment: Write a for loop going from 1 to n and rename each file with the .jpg extension going from 1 to n.  My problem is getting n. Also renaming the files, but I am taking it one step at a time.  I'm quite new to bash unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Deafsilver, sharing your research helps everyone. Show us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you mean `find . -name '*.jpg' | wc -l`? Ignore this comment if I didn't catch your point.

Comment: @Deafsilver: Why do you want total # of files? just for renaming them?

Comment: OK, so let's say `n` is at 5. What will you do with the number 5?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to count the number of files in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for file in *.jpg
do
    mv -i "$file" "$i.jpg"
    (( i++ ))
done
```